# npm config delete is not working

Tags: npm, nvm

I'm trying to delete the prefix config on npm because nvm does not play well with it.

```
(venv) ip-192-168-0-12:lending jason$ npm config delete -g prefix
(venv) ip-192-168-0-12:lending jason$ npm config delete prefix
(venv) ip-192-168-0-12:lending jason$ npm config get prefix
/Users/jason/Workspace/lending/nenv
```

However, how matter how I try to delete it, the config just wont go away.

I tried `npm config edit` and prefix wasn't even in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is the environmental variable `npm_config_prefix` was set.

Just set that to blank: `export npm_config_prefix=""`